# Prove that $n^4-n$ is divisible by 2 for all integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modules, divisibility

Here n is an integer. And for any integer number $n^4-n$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math formatting on this site. I think you mean $n^4-n$ and not $n^{4-n}$, but it should be clearer. Also, what have you tried? Have you, for instance, checked for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3$ and $4$ that it is true?

Comment: This factors as $n(n^3-1)$, and notice that $n$ and $n^3$ have the same parity.  See where this is going?

Comment: real or integer?

Comment: In the *field* of real numbers, any number is divisible by any nonzero number, so it suffices to note that $2\not=0$. Surely you mean for $n$ to be an integer (as the title suggests).

Comment: Yes, I have checked by writing a program in C++. @Arthur

Comment: $n^4$ and $n$ are either both even or both odd. Hence the difference is even.

Answer (score 4):

If $n$ is an integer, then $$n^4-n=n(n^3-1)=n(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$$

But there is an even intger amoung any two consecutive integers. ($n$ and $n-1$)

Therefore $2|n^4-n$.

Comment: I think maybe you meant "$n$ and $n-1$ "

Comment: @Ovi yes... I fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series)
gives
$$
n^4-n=14 \binom{n}{2}+ 36 \binom{n}{3}+ 24 \binom{n}{4},
$$
a sum of even numbers.

A simpler solution is to use induction. Let $a_n=n^4-n$. Then
$$
a_{n+1}-a_n = 4 n^3 + 6 n^2 + 4 n
$$
implies that $a_n$ is even for all $n$ because $a_0=0$ is even.